# Extract values and labels of labelled data

Tags: r

I am struggling to extract the a values and labels of labelled data as a data.frame in R. In the following example, I would like to extract a two column data frame of **value** and **label**.

Your time and help is much appreciated.

```
download.file("http://mqasim.me/temp/Workingdata.RData", "Workingdata11.RData")
load("Workingdata11.RData")

library(labelled)
df <- wvs2i$V2

str(df)
Class 'labelled'  atomic [1:24558] 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 32 ...
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr "Country/region"
  ..- attr(*, "format.stata")= chr "%8.0g"
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= Named num [1:197] -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 4 8 12 16 20 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:197] "Missing; Unknown" "Not asked in survey" "Not applicable" "No answer" ...

head(df)

<Labelled double>
[1] 32 32 32 32 32 32

Labels:
 value                 label
    -5      Missing; Unknown
    -4   Not asked in survey
    -3        Not applicable
    -2             No answer
    -1            Don't know
     4           Afghanistan
     8               Albania
    12               Algeria
    16        American Samoa
    20               Andorra
    24                Angola
    28               Antigua
    31            Azerbaijan
    32             Argentina
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

label and values are stored as an attribute of `df`. You can get what you want by:

```
stack(attr(df, 'labels'))

#     values                   ind
# 1       -5      Missing; Unknown
# 2       -4   Not asked in survey
# 3       -3        Not applicable
# 4       -2             No answer
# 5       -1            Don't know
# 6        4           Afghanistan
# ......
```

Comment: Excellent answer, this is exactly what I was after. Thanks for your prompt response.