# Extract maxmimum and minimum from head() function?

Tags: r, max, min, head

I am analysing segments of vectors, and for that I need to extract their maximum.

The normal way to do this would be with `max(vector, na.rm = TRUE)`.
However, in some segments the actual maximum of the vector doesn't appear, so it gives the maximum of that segment of the vector.

For this, I want to extract the maximum from the head() function, as it appears here:

```
library(expss)

nps = c(-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

var_lab(nps) = "Net promoter score"
val_lab(nps) = num_lab("-1 Detractors
                         0 Neutralists    
                         1 Promoters")

head(nps)

Output:
Detractors  -1  Detractors      
Neutralists  0  Neutralists     
Promoters    1  Promoters
```

In this case, I would want to extract '1' from the middle column. I have tried turning the output of head() into a dataframe but that just gives the first 5 values of the vector. Any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't look like a `vector`.  Is it a `data.frame`  `max(head(vector)$value)` and for both `range(head(vector)$value)`

Comment: @akrun the head() output doesn't seem like a dataframe. This is what I get with that code: ```Error in head(df$E033)$value : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors```

Comment: okay, please update your post with `dput(head(vector))` It could be that it is a `matrix`

Comment: @akrun I used ```dput(head(vector))``` and it gave me this:
```structure(c(6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5), labels = c(`Missing; Unknown` = -5, 
`Not asked in survey` = -4, `Not applicable` = -3, `No answer` = -2, 
`DonÂ´t know` = -1, Left = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, 
`6` = 6, `7` = 7, `8` = 8, `9` = 9, Right = 10), class = "labelled")```

Comment: Is it the correct structure.  I don't get the same output you showed in the post.  Any packages to load?

Comment: I am using the head() function from the ```Matrix``` package. The vector is an item column from the World Values Survey, so it has -5 to 10, which represent the things shown in the output of the post.

Comment: Can you please update your post with reproducible example

Comment: @IceCreamToucan it is actually class 'labelled', and I need it to be labelled so that the maximum (in this case value 10, labelled 'Right') is consistent across segments of the vector. What I need to do is extract the number 10 from the output.

Comment: I tried loading the `Matrix` package, but it is still not giving the exact output you showed.  If you can show how you created the data, woul dbe useful

Comment: @akrun I have updated the post with reproducible data. Let me know if you get the same output and, if possible, how to extract the maximum (1) from the output.

Comment: I get `min(nps)#
[1] -1` and `range(nps)
[1] -1  1`  Am i missing something?  Or  `min(head(nps))
[1] -1`

Comment: I double checked with selecting only two values `max(head(nps, 2))
[1] 0`

Comment: You can use the `n` argument `head(nps, 3)`

Comment: @akrun ```max(head(nps))``` works because 1 appeared as one of the first 6 values, I have updated it so that 1 appears later, and with that now it gives the max as 0, so that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your values have labels then simplest way is to extract maximum from value labels:

```
library(expss)
vec = structure(c(6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5), labels = c(`Missing; Unknown` = -5, `Not asked in survey` = -4, `Not applicable` = -3, `No answer` = -2, `DonÂ´t know` = -1, Left = 1, `2` = 2, `3` = 3, `4` = 4, `5` = 5, `6` = 6, `7` = 7, `8` = 8, `9` = 9, Right = 10), class = "labelled")

max(val_lab(vec))
# 10
```

If your vector has some values without labels, then you can use `unique`:

```
nps = c(-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
var_lab(nps) = "Net promoter score"
# no label for 1
val_lab(nps) = num_lab("-1 Detractors
                         0 Neutralists")
# nmax = 1 indicate that unique will return values from vector and values from labels 
max(unique(nps, nmax = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nps = c(-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)

var_lab(nps) = "Net promoter score"
val_lab(nps) = num_lab("-1 Detractors
                         0 Neutralists
                         1 Promoters")

max(stack(attr(nps, 'labels'))$values)
[1] 1
```

This solution was derivative from the answer here: [Extract values and labels of labelled data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44632450/extract-values-and-labels-of-labelled-data)